# Swapping bytes of an integer in Java

Tags: java, integer

I have this tiny function that expects an `int` and returns an `int` with the bytes swapped:

```
public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cafeBabe = 0xcafebabe;
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(cafeBabe));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(byteSwap(cafeBabe)));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(byteSwap(byteSwap(cafeBabe))));
    }
    
    public static int byteSwap(int a) {
        return ((a & 0xff000000) >>> 24) |
               ((a & 0x00ff0000) >>> 8)  |
               ((a & 0x0000ff00) << 8)   |
               ((a & 0x000000ff) << 24);
    }
}
```

Basically, we are switching between endianess. Now, is there a better/more efficient way of accomplishing the task?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Historical Note

The very first comment on the OP's question -- long before any answers were posted -- was a question asked by myself, and it very pointedly asked:

> Without using [Integer.reverseBytes(cafeBabe)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes(int))?

The question was two-fold:

1. Point out to the OP that a built-in method exists, and is likely the most optimal way of doing this.
2. Ask if they are trying to [reinvent-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinvent-the-wheel).

That comment/question has been removed.  If the OP responded to it, the response has been deleted as well and I never saw it.

This answer is not advocating the OP [reinvent-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinvent-the-wheel).  The Java JVM / JIT will have implemented the most efficient way of performing the operation, using internal features (such as `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate`) that are not necessarily available to the end-user.

## Reinventing the wheel

```
public static int byteSwap(int a) {
    return ((a & 0xff000000) >>> 24) |
           ((a & 0x00ff0000) >>> 8)  |
           ((a & 0x0000ff00) << 8)   |
           ((a & 0x000000ff) << 24);
}
```

This function uses 6 distinct constants, 4 AND operations, 4 shifts, and 3 OR operations.

There is no point with the AND operation in `((a & 0xff000000) >>> 24)` or in `((a & 0x000000ff) << 24)` since the 24 bits which are being masked are immediately shifted out anyway.  This removes 2 constants, and 2 AND operations, which reduces the code to:

```
public static int byteSwap(int a) {
    return (a >>> 24)               |
           ((a & 0x00ff0000) >>> 8) |
           ((a & 0x0000ff00) << 8)  |
           (a << 24);
}
```

By reworking the order of second operation, we can remove another constant, the `0x00ff0000`, and instead reuse the `0xff00` constant.  This eliminates the loading of the third bit mask constant, saving additional JVM byte code instructions:

```
public static int byteSwap(int a) {
    return (a >>> 24)           |
           ((a >>> 8) & 0xff00) |
           ((a & 0xff00) << 8)  |
           (a << 24);
}
```

This reworked version is very similar to the built-in [`Integer.reverseBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes(int)) code in the system library:

```
@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate
public static int reverseBytes(int i) {
    return (i << 24)            |
           ((i & 0xff00) << 8)  |
           ((i >>> 8) & 0xff00) |
           (i >>> 24);
}
```

I don't know if the difference in ordering gains any additional speed, but (dollars to donuts) the `@HotSpotIntrinsicCandidate` annotation probably does - so just use the built-in function.

Comment: While the masking in `(a & 0x000000FF) << 24` has no effect in this case, it sure adds its fair portion to readability. Since OP was asking for a _more efficient way_ I'd at least mention that this kind of optimization is in the most obvious realms of _micro optimizations_, Also there is a builtin function `reverseBytes(int)`.

Answer (score 6):

I like it, simple to read.

---

Personally, I prefer to keep operators on the new line, makes it easier to see how the lines belong together:

```java
return ((a & 0xff000000) >>> 24)
     | ((a & 0x00ff0000) >>> 8)
     | ((a & 0x0000ff00) << 8)
     | ((a & 0x000000ff) << 24);
```

To follow your formatting convention.

---

You could putt the first and last byte underneath each other, to make the pattern even better visible:

```java
return ((a & 0xff000000) >>> 24)
     | ((a & 0x000000ff) << 24)
     | ((a & 0x00ff0000) >>> 8)
     | ((a & 0x0000ff00) << 8);
```

That removes the pattern from the masks, but allows to easier deduce how the bytes are being moved.

---

You could also convert the `int` to a `byte` array (for example with the help of a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)), and reverse that array before converting it back. But as far as effectiveness goes, I think this should be the one with the least operations, as basically any operation on a `byte` array would have to do the same thing and more.

---

As already pointed out, there is already [`Integer.reverseBytes(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#reverseBytes-int-) which is available since 1.5.

Comment: With `ByteBuffer` you can simply reverse the endianess and then read back the `int`, no need to do that manually (always look at the methods of a class :) ).